# How do I make my responsive hamburger menu show up and hide with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just trying to teach myself some (vanilla) Javascript at the moment, so I'm assuming this is probably a pretty basic question.

At the moment, I've already displayed and hidden the hamburger menu with CSS media queries, so when the page is loaded up for the first time, it works exactly as it should.

**The problem:**

After the JS script is run (on click) to open the hamburger menu and I widen my window again, the hamburger menu stays on the screen along with the nav that's supposed to show up past the breakpoint.

What I have tried is to use an if statement to basically do some sort of Javascript media query magic.

```js
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 48.62rem)').matches) {document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display = "block";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display = "none";
      };
```

What ends up happening is the same thing as before where the hamburger menu stays on screen if I go from a smaller window to a wider one BUT clicking it again makes it vanish. Good stuff, but now when I make my window smaller again, the menu has completely vanished.

I'm fairly new to JS, so what I understand is that the script is run, it overrides the css media queries and keeps the page like that. I'm thinking a loop might be my solution (maybe a while loop?), but I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

Here's all the HTML, CSS and Javascript:

```js
function openNav(){
    document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("menu-items").style.width = "100%";
};
function closeNav(){
    document.getElementById("menu-items").style.width = "0";

    if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 48.62rem)').matches) {document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display = "block";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display = "none";
    };
    
};
```

```css
 #nav {
    display: none;
  }
  
#mobile-nav{
  float:right;
}
.open-nav {
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.5rem 4rem 0 0;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.menu-items{
  text-align: center;
  width: 0%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 50;
  position:fixed;
  background: rgba(24,24,24,0.9);
  transition:0.5s;
  display:block;
}

.menu-items a{
  clear:right;
  display:block;
  font-size: 1.25;
  padding:1em 0;
  transition:0.3s
}

.close-nav{
  float:right;
  margin:0.5rem 1em 0 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  color:rgb(206, 206, 206);
}



/* Media Queries*/
@media (min-width: 48.6rem) {
  /* Nav */
  #nav-bar{
    display:flex;
  }
  #nav {
    float:right;
    margin:0 5rem 0 0;
    display: flex;
  }

  #nav li {
    margin-right: 1em;
  }

  #mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="menu-items" class="menu-items">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-nav" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#section1" class="link lt-txt">...</a>
        <a href="#" class="link lt-txt">...</a>
        <a href="#" class="link lt-txt">...</a>
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
          <!--LOGO-->
          <div id="logo"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" /></div>
          <!--Mobile Nav-->
          <div id="mobile-nav">
            <span class="open-nav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
          </div>

          <!--Main Nav-->
          <ul id="nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#section1" class="link">...</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link">...</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link">...</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Unless there’s something specific that needs to be measured, I find it is better to use (change) class names exclusively so it is clearer in your CSS what is happening.

Comment: An approach to solve this could be to listen for resize events on the window. Once the window is bigger than your limit and the hamburger menu is shown, hide it.

Comment: @D_N you know, that's actually the best solution for something as simple as a menu bar. Simple and it just works.

Purely out of curiosity though, if that was not an option for whatever reason and I had to do it the way I initially planned to (with a loop or something), what would you think would be best?

Comment: @jollywhiskers I know this kind of answer is annoying, but I really wouldn’t do that. The browser repaints CSS changes really quickly, and why replicate its effort in your own JS? There needs to be a specific need for JS’s capabilities to justify the expense and the mixing of presentation and interaction layers. Especially with a cohesive CSS framework or method (see BEM).

Comment: If you were to need to reassess things on browser resize, though, make sure you use the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) and to stash your elements in variables if they are called multiple times so it doesn’t have to look them up again. I sometimes assign to the window resize event and then manually call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling CSS classes is way more cleaner and easier than using JavaScript style attribute. You should use it that way :

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#responsive-menu");
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");

btn.onclick = function() {
  nav.classList.toggle("expand");
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: none;  
  background-color: #ed0;
}

nav.expand {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="responsive-menu">Click me</button>
<nav>
  Menu
</nav>
```

And to specify different CSS for some media size, use [CSS media queries](https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/930-css3-media-queries.html).